# Error assigning to non-lvalue 'uxCurrentEventBits' event_groups.c

Tags: c, freertos

I am trying to run a FreeRTOS project on mikroC for ARM, but I get an assigning to non-lvalue 'uxCurrentEventBits' error. Please help fix it.

I downloaded an example from this source https://libstock.mikroe.com/projects/view/2083/freertos-v9-0-0-mikroc-examples

Where the error occurs:

```
const EventBits_t uxCurrentEventBits = pxEventBits->uxEventBits;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by installing the latest version of the compiler.